# AS3 - Best method for dynamically creating a series of text fields?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, text

I am (successfully) creating a column of boxes via a loop, the meat of which is:

```
for(var i=0; i  < MAX_ROWS + 1; i++){
                for(var o=0; o < MAX_COLS + 1; o++){
                    var currentTile:MemberBox = new MemberBox();
                    currentTile.x = i*150;
                    currentTile.y = o*25;
                    currentTile.name = "b"+o;
                    memberBox.addChild(currentTile);
}}
```

Now I need to add a textfield to each box, which will later be populated with data from an array.  I tried adding each textfield to an array in the for loop and then calling from the array, but the textfields still all have the same name so only the last one called actually works...

Here is what I have - it almost does what I need, but it only adds text to the last box created.

```
var txtArray:Array = new Array();

for(var i=0; i  < MAX_ROWS + 1; i++){
for(var o=0; o < MAX_COLS + 1; o++){
var currentTile:MemberBox = new MemberBox();
currentTile.x = i*150;
currentTile.y = o*25;
currentTile.name = "b"+o;
memberBox.addChild(currentTile);

currentTile.addChild(memberBoxText);
memberBoxText.width = 150;
memberBoxText.height = 25;
txtArray[o] = memberBoxText;
txtArray[o].text = "test"+o;
}}
```

Comment: Well you didn't declare anywhere memberBoxText so I asume you added it manually through flash builder. You are not making new instance of your textField.Try inserting this into for loop: var memberTxt:TextField=new TextField(); currentTile.addChild(memberTxt);

Comment: Sorry, left that out.  memberBoxText is declared in the class `public var memberBoxText:TextField = new TextField;`

Comment: Ohh!  I see, yes changing it to declaring the variable inside the loop did the trick.  Thank you!  Please add as answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you didn't declare anywhere memberBoxText so I asume you added it manually through flash builder. You are not making new instance of your textField.Try inserting this into for loop: 
`var memberTxt:TextField=new TextField(); currentTile.addChild(memberTxt);` 
:)